# How to update user information in firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

i have this function to change user email. I'm able to change the email and i can see it in firebase console, but when i go return to my application to see user info, i see only the old email presented.

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    currentUser?.updateEmail(to: emailTextField.text!) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            self.userDocRef = self.db.collection("users").document(self.auth.currentUser!.uid)
            self.userDocRef?.getDocument(completion: {(snapshot, error) in
                guard snapshot != nil else { print("Error:", error!); return }
                let userData = snapshot!.data()!
                self.emailTextField.text = userData["email"]! as? String
            })
            print("CHANGED")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What code your application use when you say `i go return to my application to see user info`? Are you using `currentUser`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes

Comment: Can you update the code to print `Auth.auth().currentUser?.email` inside the callback? As far as I can see, that should be updated. If it isn't updated for you, edit your question to show the updated code, and the output of the print statement.

Comment: You've omitted a step... You're updating the user FIREBASE object here `currentUser?.updateEmail` but then reading a node from Firebase that contains a field called 'email' here `self.userDocRef?.getDocument` which is unrelated. If you're storing the users email in both the Firebase user object *as well as* in a document, you would need to update both.